# Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked at the other answers but they haven't helped.

```
$postid = $_GET['p'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT comment_id,comment_submitter_id,comment_text,comment_lava,comment_icy,comment_date,comment_parent,post_id FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? AND comment_parent = 0');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $postid);
```

When I run the same SQL in phpmyadmin, it fetches the rows fine (? replaced with 1). My query string is ?p=1. How can this possibly be failing?

---

```
  $postid = $_GET['p'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $postid);

  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->bind_result($post_id, $post_submitter_id, $post_title, $post_text, $post_lava, $post_icy, $post_url, $post_nsfw, $post_views, $post_date, $post_heat, $post_sub);

  $stmt->fetch();
```

some HTML, then more PHP

---

```
      $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT comment_id,comment_submitter_id,comment_text,comment_lava,comment_icy,comment_date,comment_parent,post_id FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? AND comment_parent = 0');
      $query->bind_param('s', $postid);
      $query->execute();
      $query->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_submitter_id, $comment_text, $comment_lava, $comment_icy, $comment_date, $comment_parent, $post_id);

      while($query->fetch()){

        $posts[] = [
             'comment_id' => $comment_id,
             'comment_submitter_id' => $post_submitter_id,
             'comment_text' => $comment_text,
             'comment_lava' => $comment_lava,
             'comment_icy' => $comment_icy,
             'comment_date' => $comment_date,
             'comment_parent' => $comment_parent,
             'comment_post_id' => $post_id
        ];

      }
```

Comment: Really? None of the other answers suggested just asking `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Where is your connection? Show your connection code.

Comment: In bind param replace s with i

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);`

Comment: @Shehary still same error

Comment: @frosty Check for errors: `if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conn->connect_error);
}` otherwise you also won't see them

Comment: I have that too.. my previous db query works fine

Comment: You have to show us your **full** and **real** code. Something fails and makes your connection to a boolean.

Comment: I deleted the previous query and no more errors came up, but I've tried using `$stmt2` instead and the error still comes up. So is the previous query interfering with it?

Comment: if previous db query works fine, may b you need to check `$postid` may be it's empty, echo it and see if it returns value and in your bind parameter replace `$postid` with `1` and see if you get result, like `Kill two birds with one stone`

Comment: check my edit. that's the full code

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title, which I assume is the error you're getting, your prepared statement is failing to be created. The issue is before you even call bind_param, it's on "prepare" (or earlier).

This could be for a number of reasons, so we would really need to see more code.

Comment: I added the previous query that seems to be interfering with it